# MATLAB: constructing a column vector whose only element is character A

Tags: matlab

I want a column vector that contains only the character A, that is,

```
 A
 A
 A
 A
```

like this. So i have tried

```
 'A'*ones(4,1)
```

But in place of A, it takes on value 65. How can i get A ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
repmat('A',4,1)
```

Or use your approach but include `char` to convert back to string after the multiplication:

```
char('A'*ones(4,1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Multiplication of `char`s with `double`s gives `double`s; the `char`is cast to `double`, using the corresponding ASCII value.

Just cast back to `char`:

```
char('A'*ones(4,1))
```

but probably Luis' answer is faster ;)

Comment: +1 for the more detailed explanation of what happens with the multiplication